# Remove string after length of 400 characters or 10 sentences in MySQL

Tags: mysql, string

I have a table where one field (description) can vary, and ideally I would like to either remove anything after 400 characters or after 10 sentences (but at the end of a sentence and either have nothing or add .... to make it look more natural).

I have got the position

```
SELECT description,LOCATE('.',description)   as pos
FROM table  
WHERE locate('.',description)>20;
```

But I cannot get any further; is this the best method?

Comment: Cutting it off after 10 sentences is probably more effort than it is worth.

Answer (score 0):

To truncate to 10 sentences use [substring_index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
substring_index( description, '.', 10 )
```

Your query:

```
SELECT  concat(
            left(  substring_index( description, '.', 10 )
                  ,397
                )
            ,'...' )
FROM table  
WHERE len( description ) > 400
```

Notice: not tested.